# Running SQL file from .bat script showing all results in command prompt

Tags: sql, batch-file, command-prompt

I am running a series of SQL files in a .bat script. The scripts are running correctly, however on the Windows command prompt window it is displaying all results from the final table. There are about 570,000 records and it is time consuming. How do I switch this off?

Answer (score 1):

I would redirect output to the `nul` destination.

For example, if you're running SQL Server:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S server -d database -E -i C:\myScript.sql > NUL
```

I can't give a more specific answer because you did not post your database vendor or your batch file code.

Comment: I am using both a .bat file and number of sql scripts to create the file. I am using an Oracle database and not sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database and corresponding CLI tool you're using, you can:

1. find an option for the CLI tool to make it less chatty (usually `-q` for "quiet" or similar)
2. redirect the output to the `NUL` device by appending `> NUL` to the command.
3. redirect the output to a file by appending `> logfile.txt` to the command (if you want to check the process afterwards)

Note that with the last two approaches, output may still be showing if the CLI tool is outputting to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`. In order to redirect both `STDERR` and `STDOUT`, add an additional `2>&1` to your command.